# Linq-to-SQL ToDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var allocations = 
    from ta in dc.TransactionAllocations
    where ta.Allocated == false
    group ta by new { ta.ReceiptReference, ta.Customer } into tag
    select new
    {
        Customer = tag.Key.Customer,
        ReceiptReference = tag.Key.ReceiptReference,
        Invoices = tag.ToDictionary(a => new AllocationDictionaryKey()
            {
                ID = a.ID, 
                InvoiceReference = a.InvoiceReference 
            }, 
            a => a.Amount)
    }
```

But when I try to execute this, the ToDictionary call fails as it's not a supported LINQ-to-SQL operator. The only way around this I have seen is to call ToDictionary at the end of the query, but I only want one property of my anonymous type to be a dictionary!

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at using AsEnumerable. This is designed to get round operators that are not supported by a specific platform. It means that the data will be processed where the code is rather than where the data is though.

```
Invoices = tag.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(a => new AllocationDictionaryKey() { ID = a.ID, InvoiceReference = a.InvoiceReference }, a => a.Amount)
```

Comment: Try `tag.ToArray().ToDictionary`

Comment: If @Steven's suggestion doesn't work then it could be the initial `group by` that isn't translating well in which case you'll have to load all of the data into memory first

Answer (score 2):

Quite old, but here goes.
I solved my problem with

```
 from ta in dc.TransactionAllocations.AsEnumerable()
```

i.e. directly making the datatable as Enumerable.